# How can I create a service on rosjava?

Tags: ros, android-core, service, gradle, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I'm creating and Android app to remotely operate the turtlebot_panorama app through service calls. I don't know how to make gradle to compile my .srv file.

As a dirty workaround, I copied the .srv file on

rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap/src/test/resources/test_ros/srv/

and let gradle compile it together with the whole rosjava_core. This works fine but...

Thank you a lot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53685/how-can-i-create-a-service-on-rosjava?/) by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2284 on 2013-01-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You simply need to rebuild the rosjava_messages package. For Eclipse, it depends highly on your setup. You may need to regenerate your project as well.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2013-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [denis](https://answers.ros.org/users/24974/denis/) on 2016-01-11**:
Hi, I've succesfully created a `service` (using your suggestion). I'm trying to use this package on the `rosjava_tutorial_services` package, but the compiler says that the `custom_msg` package doesn't exist. Do you have some suggestion on how to build the project in a correct way?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please look at the topic #54933.(I'm afraid that my karmas are too few to show a link.)

It can be just as vaild for the custom services.
You should rebuild rosjava,especially, rosjava_message.

---

Originally posted by [KazutoMurase](https://answers.ros.org/users/2505/kazutomurase/) with karma: 116 on 2013-02-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-02-17**:
Ups...  I'm gonna be a bit ridiculous, but....  what do you mean with topic #54933?

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-02-18**:
Apart from this, I tried in a similar way that with messages and it works.Thanks! Only black point is the ugly way I integrated the generated classes on eclipse (adding the rosjava_core's messages directory to the sources). Did you have a better way?